# location.href is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, href

I'm curently in trouble with any possible form of reading the current browser location in Firefox (v 33.1).
location.href, window.location.href and document.location.href are "undefined", if being read by jQuery's "ready" functionality. Same for .hash etc. However, in the console they return exactly what they are supposed to.

```
$(function(){$("a").unbind("click").click($S.r);$S.r();});
$S={
    r: function()
    {
        try{$I=((typeof this.href)?this.href:location.href).replace(/^.*?#/,'');}catch($E){console.error($E);setTimeout(function(){$S.r();},250);return false;}
        $S.c($I);
    },
    c: function($I)
    {
        $("content").css({"opacity":"0"});
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            $("content spacer").html($S.h($I));
            $("content").css({"opacity":"1"});
        },1000);
    },
    h: function($I)
    {
        switch ($I)
        {
            case "impressum": return "Impressum";
            case "email": return "E-Mail";
            case "mitglieder": return "Familien-Mitglieder";
            default: return "Startseite";
        }
    }
};
```

URL: http://saris.it

What I want to achieve: /#test shall trigger the script to load the content for Test
This works when clicking a link. On pageload, it does NOT.
Corresponding vars are filled in the console. They are NOT in jQuery.
Using setTimeout did NOT help at all.

How should I work arround this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error here:

```
((typeof this.href)?this.href:location.href).replace(/^.*?#/,'')
```

Try:

```
((typeof this.href != 'undefined')?this.href:location.href).replace(/^.*?#/,'')
```

Undefined not `location.href`, but `this.href`,
because your `typeof this.href` is string `'undefined'`, it's true, when comparision.

Comment: Must have removed that with either of my undo steps accidently, thanks. Added it back, however, location.href is still "undefined"

Comment: The console clearly states `TypeError: location.href is undefined`

Comment: However, I don't see this error on your site.. And `location.href` is correctly defined too. Try to clear your cache.

Comment: I totally don't see a logical explanation, why editing this stopped location.href from being undefined as the console stated, but it actually DID work. Firefox sometimes drives me nuts. Thanks.

Comment: `did work`. Isn't it work now? Or you about your console error? :)

Comment: By 'it did work', I mean your suggestion did help, eventhough it does totally not explain why location.href is defined now - and wasn't before - in any way. The error message is confusing.